# Insert to all innner array of php a variable at once

Tags: php, arrays, loops

For ex:

```
array(
    array(
        id = 1,
        name= ben,
        date = ""

    ), 
    array(
        id=2,
        name= john,
        date = ""   
    ),
    array(
        id =3,
        name= dow,
        date = ""

    )
)
```

I have this array. As you can see these are identical arrays inside another array. Which make it a multidimensional array. Is there a way that I can assign date to all the inner array without a foreach loop ?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: array_walk() or array_map() where the loop is `internal` rather than explicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_replace_recursive()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php) can be pretty useful

```
$sample = array(
    array( 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'ben'),
    array( 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'john'),
    array( 'id' => 3, 'name' => 'mark')
);

$count = count($sample);
$magic = array_fill(0, $count, array('date' => time()));

$result = array_replace_recursive($sample, $magic);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 2):

You can try `array_walk`

```
array_walk($array, function(&$value, $key){
    $value['date'] = time();
});
```

#### Output

```
var_dump($array);

array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 1
      'name' => string 'ben' (length=3)
      'date' => int 1379060666
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 2
      'name' => string 'john' (length=4)
      'date' => int 1379060666
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 3
      'name' => string 'dow' (length=3)
      'date' => int 1379060666
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not very extensible, you can hard-code it. (`array_map()` is probably better, though.)

```
$arr[0]['date'] = $date1;
$arr[1]['date'] = $date2;
$arr[2]['date'] = $date3;
```